# Properly setting TypeScript typings for anonymous functions passed to Ramda

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, ramda.js

I'm trying to figure out what the proper typings are for the Ramda cookbook method `mapKeys` it won't transpile without throwing an error.

**Issue**

Error is on `fn`:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a:
>   string) => string'. Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(a:
>   string): string'.

I can see from the typings of `R.adjust` that it uses generics, and I tried `(a: string) =>  string` based on the error, which should be the correct typings, and several other variations, such as `(a: string) => string[]`.

Can someone indicate what the `fn` argument for the anonymous function should be to fix the typings error?

This is really easy to duplicate by just pasting the example into a TypeScript project using VSCode and installing Ramda via npm, and I include the typings for `R.adjust` as a reference.

**Example**

```
import * as R from 'ramda';

export const mapKeys = R.curry(
  (fn: ???, obj: { [k: string]: any } | { [k: number]: any }) =>
    R.fromPairs(
      R.map(
        R.adjust(fn, 0), // <--- Error: tried typings for `adjust`
        R.toPairs(obj)
      )
    )
);
```

**Ramda Typings for Reference**

```
adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number, list: T[]): T[];
adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number): (list: T[]) => T[];
```

Comment: I don't know Typescript.  But that function should have a type that accepts a single String and returns a String.

Comment: I guess it could theoretically have the same `String || Number` type as `toPairs`, especially in the return, but that's probably overkill.  (Who would use it that way?)

Comment: @ScottSauyet yah I thought the same when I saw the error, but I've tried what was provided in the error message `(a: string) => string`, and `string`.  I think it might be an issue with the `adjust` typings maybe... since another method from the Ramda cookbook `renameBy` that uses `adjust` also has the same issue

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of my league.  No ideas about how TS really works.  But good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted an issue on [Github](https://github.com/types/npm-ramda/issues/273) for `types/npm-ramda` and a [fix](https://github.com/types/npm-ramda/pull/280) was merged into master for the next release of the Ramda typings.